# herokuで必要になるProcfile書き方が分からない。

Tags: python, python3, heroku, foreman

Python 3.6.4とFlaskで制作したアプリをherokuにデプロイしたいのですが、その際に必要になるProcfileの書き方がわかりません。
普段ローカル環境ではmanage.pyに引数としてwebpageと入力したサーバを立ち上げるのですが、その場合Procfileにはどのように記述したらいいのかわかりません。
解説のページなどを拝見すると
Procfileを以下のように記述しているのを見かけます。

```
web: gunicorn manage:app --log-file -
```

ですが、引数を記述したProcfileを見つける事ができませんでした。

**サーバ起動コマンド**

```
python manage.py webpage
```

**manage.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import argparse
__author__ = 'wataru'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #エラーの時にメッセージを表示する。 
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Runner")
    parser.add_argument('action', type=str, nargs=None, help="Select target webpage")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.action == 'webpage':
        from front_processing import app
        app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=9000)

    else:
        raise ValueError('Please add webpage at your command')
```

詳しい方、お力を貸して頂けると幸いです。
よろしくおねがいします。

追記
以下のページで
https://qiita.com/Shitimi_613/items/6627d0ce042d38b86893

**herokuでコマンドを直接実行**
heroku run 実行したいコマンドを入力するとheroku側でコマンドを実行できると書いてあるのですが、これを使って`heroku run python manage.py webpage`を実行させればprocfileは必要ないように思えるのですが、このようなことは可能でしょうか？
ただその場合gunicornが実行されないままになるような気がします。

**procfileの認識**
procfileとはherokuで実行させたいコマンドをあらかじめ記述しておくものと認識しているのですが、その認識であっているのでしょうか？procfileでは普通のコマンドlsやpipインストールなども実行できるのでしょうか？

**Procfileというdynosを起動するコマンド宣言するために必要なファイル**
下記のサイトでdynosを起動するコマンドをProcfileに記述するためlsやpipなどは実行できそうにないです。
http://kasoutuuka.org/heroku-hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlaskのドキュメントでGunicornでの起動方法が示されています。
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#gunicorn

Procfileに次のように記述すれば動作しないでしょうか。

```
web: gunicorn front_processing:app --log-file -
```

manage.py で次のようにアプリケーションを起動されているのでfront_processing:appがアプリケーションではないかと推測しました。

```
from front_processing import app
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=9000)
```

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。front_processingがアプリなのですが、この記述でアプリが自動で起動するのでしょうか？アプリ起動するにはheroku側でコマンドを実行しないと起動しないのでしょうか？

Comment: まずはデプロイして見てはどうでしょうか。動作しなかった場合はログなどの情報を追加されると回答できるかもしれません。

Comment: デプロイ無事に出来ました。ありがとうございます！